# Bluez Architecture : Explain this Architecture

Tags: android, c, linux, bluetooth, bluez

here i want to understand the architecture of bluez (Bluetooth Stack Protocol).

I understood how bluetooth enable in module. its enable by up the BT_EN pin in this Bluetooth Chip.
After attacth this device with `HCI UART` to Bluez for communication.

i want to know about bluez architecture and how its works.

Here i put one image of bluez overview diagram . Any please Explain me What is `Bluez Core` in this diagram.

[image]

Please explain me the flow of this diagram how bluez works in bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BlueZ Core in that diagram is the main host stack software.  It communicates with the BT hardware using HCI protocol to do general control of the hardware.  You would have to read the BT spec to get a full picture of what all of the HCI protocol commands do.  But at a high level there are things like reading HW features, versions, initiating scanning states, parsing out scanning results, managing connections, etc.

Comment: What role of the L2CAP,HCI Sockets and SCO sockets? i have knowledge only that part. first we have to initialize HCI UART driver and than we have to call some ioctl call in kernel. so please tell me why we use this ioctl call after UART driver initialization.

Comment: L2CAP is a higher level protocol for sending user data, and sits on top of HCI.  SCO is for synchronous data like voice calls.  HCI sockets are just a way for app to directly send arbitrary HCI packets transparently to the HW device.

Comment: @TJD So you are basically saying BlueZ is an implementation of Host Controller Interface. So does that mean that for establishing secured connection Levels (4,3,2,1) and/or implementing GATT services, it is level to application layer? What about L2CAP then? That too is outside the ambit of BlueZ?